# WinForms combobox displays ValueMember instead of DisplayMember

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to populate a dropdown from a DataTable, which is returned from the database. Once selected, I will run a query using the BatchNumber (int), but I want the combobox to display the LastRun (formatted DateTime). I have verified that the column names match.

For some reason, BatchNumber is being displayed. When printing out cboLastRunTime.DisplayMember, BatchNumber is also displayed there even though I have set it to LastRun.  I've read numerous articles on this topic and have played around with databinding and other techniques; nothing has worked. How do I display the DisplayMember?

I'm pretty new to Windows Forms. Please let me know if you need more information.

```
    private void GetLastRunTimes()
    {
        _dataTable = _process.GetLastRunTimes(); //retrieves data from DB
        cboxLastRunTimes.DataSource = _dataTable;
        cboxLastRunTimes.DisplayMember = "LastRun";
        cboxLastRunTimes.ValueMember = "BatchNumber";
    }
```

EDIT: Here is where I use the values from the combobox:

```
    private void btnGetPastResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int resultId = Convert.ToInt32(cboxLastRunTimes.SelectedValue);
            GetPreviousReconciliationInfo(resultId);
            if (_resultsDT != null)
                LoadDataGrid(); 
            //other UI changes
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error handling
        }
     }

    private void GetPreviousReconciliationInfo(int batchNumber)
    {
        _resultsDT = _process.Reconcile_GetPreviousReconciliationInfo(batchNumber); //retrieves data from DB
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the comboboxes SelectionChanged event to get the value or some other method?  You need to show us the code you are using to retrieve the comboboxes data.

Comment: Swap the order of the lines, it's a known issue.

Comment: @jpaugh78 - I have not included the handler, but I was under the impression I only needed it if I wanted to trigger an event on a selection change. This method is being called on the form Load. The options in the dropdown display incorrectly from the very beginning, and an event is only triggered once a secondary button is clicked.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - Tried that... same issue.

Comment: Just to be clear, set them in this order:  `ValueMember`, `DisplayMember`, `DataSource`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - that results in a printout of "System.Data.DataRowView"

Comment: Do you get the "System.Data.DataRowView" result every time you press the button or just that one time when you are getting the value during the form load?  You might be trying to get the value before your combo box has been databound.

Comment: If I set DataSource after the members, I get "System.Data.DataRowView" at all points - when the form loads and after the button is clicked. (If I set it before, the ValueMember displays.) Though the code is still pulling values correctly because data is returned from the database as expected. Is there some kind of conversion I can do to get the value out of the RowView?

Comment: Check again if column "LastRun" exists in the `datatable`. Your datatable variable is defined on form scope. Change it to method scope to be sure nothing change it

Comment: @Fabio Ah! There was an intermediate conversion that changed the name of the column en route, took a little digging to find it. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

While the column name in the Database was LastRun, it was converted to LastReconciledTime en route from the SQLClient. Changing the value of the DisplayMember to LastReconciledTime fixed it.

Thanks to @Fabio for the reminder to double-check!